# Azure AD to authenticate users to public facing webapp

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have a nodejs webapp with login, signup pages (text fields to enter username, passwd and "Login" button). Other pages in the UI and Backend APIs should be accessible only to authenticated users.

What options do i have if i want to authenticate users using Azure AD (Clicking the "Login" button on the UI should authenticate against Azure AD)? Would the flow be different If i want to authenticate both internal (associates with AD credentials) and external users (end customers not in our AD)

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

> What options do i have if i want to authenticate users using Azure AD
>   (Clicking the "Login" button on the UI should authenticate against
>   Azure AD)?

In the B2C, you could use the [direct sign-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/direct-signin) by the username or the identity provider.

> Would the flow be different If i want to authenticate both internal
>   (associates with AD credentials) and external users (end customers not
>   in our AD)

There is no difference. If you don't set up direct sign-in, all the user will see the first page for the user to choose the provider, and then will redirect to the related provider login page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a B2C directory and create a web app there, then you can create Signin or Sign Up Policy. Once you are able to create that, open it and select the web app you have created and a redirect url to which you want your user to redirect to afetr successful login. Now hit the Run Now button at the bottom of the policy page. You should see a login page. If you are using it for the 1st time, you have to sign up otherwise you can signin directly. That will do for you.

There is no diff if you are signing in a user who has the ad credentials or not. They still have to signup in the b2c directory for the 1st time as the user profile they have is for the Azure AD directory and not for Azure AD B2C.

There is one thing to consider in min, what type of Authentication you want to follow, OpenId or EasyAuth.

You can test these things out and that should solve your problem. If you still face any challenge, you can let me know here.